# Using Eigen with custom complex number designed for Automatic Differentiation

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm having trouble using a custom scalar type in mixed expression in the Eigen Library.  I followed the instructions for adding custom scalar types given
 here https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_CustomScalar.html.  Despite following these I cannot get my code to compile. I'm assuming I just didn't follow the instructions correctly so I'm hoping somebody can help tell me what I did wrong.

To be specific I've boiled down my problem to a very simple example.  I have a type called "cplx"(you can find it here:http://mdolab.engin.umich.edu/sites/default/files/complexify.h_0.txt), which I use to do complex numerical differentiation.  I'm trying to use cplx as a scalar type within Eigen.  I followed the instructions linked above and produced the following NumTraits struct,

```
template<> struct NumTraits<cplx> : NumTraits<std::complex<double>>
{
    typedef double Real;
    typedef cplx NonInteger;
    typedef cplx Nested;

    enum {
        IsComplex = 1,
        IsInteger = 0,
        IsSigned = 1,
        RequireInitialization = 1,
        ReadCost = 2 * NumTraits<double>::ReadCost,
        AddCost = 2 * NumTraits<double>::AddCost,
        MulCost = 4 * NumTraits<double>::MulCost + 2 * NumTraits<double>::AddCost
    };

};
```

I then want to construct expressions of the following form:

```
Eigen::Matrix<cplx, 3, 10> dc;
Eigen::Matrix<double, 10, 3> dNdx;
Eigen::Matrix<cplx, 3, 3> Fc = dc * dNdx;
```

When I try to compile this I get following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2672   'Eigen::internal::gebp_traits<cplx,double,false,false>::madd': no matching overloaded function found    Simulation_MechanicalTest   c:\users\nick.burgess\documents\code\toolsets\eigen\3.3.3\source\eigen\src\core\products\generalblockpanelkernel.h  999 
Error   C2782   'void Eigen::internal::gebp_traits<cplx,double,false,false>::madd(const LhsPacketType &,const RhsPacketType &,AccPacketType &,AccPacketType &) const': template parameter 'AccPacketType' is ambiguous  Simulation_MechanicalTest   c:\users\nick.burgess\documents\code\toolsets\eigen\3.3.3\source\eigen\src\core\products\generalblockpanelkernel.h  999 
Error   C2784   'void Eigen::internal::gebp_traits<cplx,double,false,false>::madd(const LhsPacketType &,const RhsPacketType &,AccPacketType &,AccPacketType &) const': could not deduce template argument for 'AccPacketType &' from 'double'   Simulation_MechanicalTest   c:\users\nick.burgess\documents\code\toolsets\eigen\3.3.3\source\eigen\src\core\products\generalblockpanelkernel.h  999 
Error   C2672   'Eigen::internal::gebp_traits<cplx,double,false,false>::madd': no matching overloaded function found    Simulation_MechanicalTest   c:\users\nick.burgess\documents\code\toolsets\eigen\3.3.3\source\eigen\src\core\products\generalblockpanelkernel.h  1000    
Error   C2782   'void Eigen::internal::gebp_traits<cplx,double,false,false>::madd(const LhsPacketType &,const RhsPacketType &,AccPacketType &,AccPacketType &) const': template parameter 'AccPacketType' is ambiguous  Simulation_MechanicalTest   c:\users\nick.burgess\documents\code\toolsets\eigen\3.3.3\source\eigen\src\core\products\generalblockpanelkernel.h  1000    
Error   C2784   'void Eigen::internal::gebp_traits<cplx,double,false,false>::madd(const LhsPacketType &,const RhsPacketType &,AccPacketType &,AccPacketType &) const': could not deduce template argument for 'AccPacketType &' from 'double'   Simulation_MechanicalTest   c:\users\nick.burgess\documents\code\toolsets\eigen\3.3.3\source\eigen\src\core\products\generalblockpanelkernel.h  1000    
Error   C2672   'Eigen::internal::gebp_traits<cplx,double,false,false>::madd': no matching overloaded function found    Simulation_MechanicalTest   c:\users\nick.burgess\documents\code\toolsets\eigen\3.3.3\source\eigen\src\core\products\generalblockpanelkernel.h  1001    
Error   C2782   'void Eigen::internal::gebp_traits<cplx,double,false,false>::madd(const LhsPacketType &,const RhsPacketType &,AccPacketType &,AccPacketType &) const': template parameter 'AccPacketType' is ambiguous  Simulation_MechanicalTest   c:\users\nick.burgess\documents\code\toolsets\eigen\3.3.3\source\eigen\src\core\products\generalblockpanelkernel.h  1001    
Error   C2784   'void Eigen::internal::gebp_traits<cplx,double,false,false>::madd(const LhsPacketType &,const RhsPacketType &,AccPacketType &,AccPacketType &) const': could not deduce template argument for 'AccPacketType &' from 'double'   Simulation_MechanicalTest   c:\users\nick.burgess\documents\code\toolsets\eigen\3.3.3\source\eigen\src\core\products\generalblockpanelkernel.h  1001    
Error   C2782   'void Eigen::internal::gebp_traits<cplx,double,false,false>::madd(const LhsPacketType &,const RhsPacketType &,AccPacketType &,AccPacketType &) const': template parameter 'AccPacketType' is ambiguous  Simulation_MechanicalTest   c:\users\nick.burgess\documents\code\toolsets\eigen\3.3.3\source\eigen\src\core\products\generalblockpanelkernel.h  1002    
Error   C2672   'Eigen::internal::gebp_traits<cplx,double,false,false>::madd': no matching overloaded function found    Simulation_MechanicalTest   c:\users\nick.burgess\documents\code\toolsets\eigen\3.3.3\source\eigen\src\core\products\generalblockpanelkernel.h  1002
```

Has anyone ran into this error before.  I'm quite confused about what might be wrong?  As part of trying to debug I did of course try expressions like

```
Eigen::Matrix<cplx, 3, 10> dc;
Eigen::Matrix<cplx, 10, 3> dNdx;
Eigen::Matrix<cplx, 3, 3> Fc = dc * dNdx;
```

which compiles just fine.  No errors at all.  So it is clearly an issue mixing double and cplx together.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Mickael, Thanks for formatting that...tried to get it into a source code block 3 times but failed.  How did you get it to look like that?

Answer (score 1):

By default Eigen will not allow mixing different scalar types in expressions (no implicit casting).

```
Eigen::Matrix<float, 4,4> Af;
Eigen::Matrix<double,4,4> Ad;
// Af*Ad;  // not allowed
Af.cast<double>()*Ad; // explicitly cast Af to double
```

To allow mixing different scalar types, you can either explicitly cast one type to the other as above, or specialize the following traits (additionally to `Eigen::NumTraits`):

```
namespace Eigen{
  template<typename BinOp>
  struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<cplx,double,BinOp>
  { typedef cplx ReturnType; };
  template<typename BinOp>
  struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<double,cplx,BinOp>
  { typedef cplx ReturnType; };
}
```

This should also allow adding, subtracting and dividing `cplx` and `double` expressions (I did not test this with your code).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you; I'm using visual studio 2017 CE with compiler option set to c++17. I had to disable sdl checks. I ported your complex class into a header file and here is what I'm seeing:

If you define this and try to compile it works without error:

```
Eigen::Matrix<cplx, 3, 10> dc;
Eigen::Matrix<double, 10, 3> dNdx;
```

However when you try to declare your third instantiation of your Eigen Matrix

```
Eigen::Matrix<cplx, 3, 3> Fc = dc * dNdx;
```

This is where the compiler errors are coming from; Try to expand out the expressions and this might help you.

```
Eigen::Matrix<cplx, 3, 3> = Eigen::Matrix<cplx, 3, 10> * Eigen::Matrix<double, 10, 3>
```

It appears that you are getting a compilation error with either an `operator=`, `operator*` or both because it doesn't know how to resolve the ambiguity of the simple expressions

```
cplx = cplx * double.
```

It doesn't know how to convert from a double to a cplx, either there is no conversion defined or the template instantiation is ambiguous.

---

**EDIT**

I did a little more research into your situation. In your header I commented out the line `using namespace std;` And just used the `std::` resolution operator where needed, thinking that maybe there was a conflict between library namespaces. This ended up giving me the same exact results from compilation.

My next step was that I took all of your user defined overloaded constructors and for any constructor that is taking only a single parameter I prefixed them with `explicit`. They now look like this:

```
cplx() : std::complex<double>() {};
explicit cplx( const double& d ) : std::complex<double>( d ) {};
cplx( const double& r, const double& i ) : std::complex<double>( r, i ) {};
explicit cplx( const std::complex<double>& z ) : std::complex<double>( z ) {};
explicit cplx( const std::complex<float>& z ) : std::complex<double>( z ) {};
```

I also added a `cpp file` to this `.h` just so I can simply compile this file alone.

A majority of your overloads and some of your functions are now all giving me the same exact compiler error from MSVC.

> error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'std::complex' to 'cplx'

These operators and functions are the ones that are giving this error:

```
inline cplx cplx::operator+() const {
    return +std::complex<double>( *this );
}

inline cplx cplx::operator+( const cplx& z ) const {
    return std::complex<double>( *this ) + std::complex<double>( z );
}

inline cplx cplx::operator+( const double& r ) const {
    return std::complex<double>( *this ) + r;
}

inline cplx cplx::operator+( const int& i ) const {
    return std::complex<double>( *this ) + double( i );
}

inline cplx operator+( const double& r, const cplx& z ) {
    return r + std::complex<double>( z );
}

inline cplx operator+( const int& i, const cplx& z ) {
    return double( i ) + std::complex<double>( z );
}

inline cplx cplx::operator-() const {
    return -std::complex<double>( *this );
}

inline cplx cplx::operator-( const cplx& z ) const {
    return std::complex<double>( *this ) - std::complex<double>( z );
}

inline cplx cplx::operator-( const double& r ) const {
    return std::complex<double>( *this ) - r;
}

inline cplx cplx::operator-( const int& i ) const {
    return std::complex<double>( *this ) - double( i );
}

inline cplx operator-( const double& r, const cplx& z ) {
    return r - std::complex<double>( z );
}

inline cplx operator-( const int& i, const cplx& z ) {
    return double( i ) - std::complex<double>( z );
}

inline cplx cplx::operator*( const cplx& z ) const {
    return std::complex<double>( *this )*std::complex<double>( z );
}

inline cplx cplx::operator*( const double& r ) const {
    return std::complex<double>( *this )*r;
}

inline cplx cplx::operator*( const int& i ) const {
    return std::complex<double>( *this )*double( i );
}

inline cplx operator*( const double& r, const cplx& z ) {
    return r * std::complex<double>( z );
}

inline cplx operator*( const int& i, const cplx& z ) {
    return double( i )*std::complex<double>( z );
}

inline cplx cplx::operator/( const cplx& z ) const {
    return std::complex<double>( *this ) / std::complex<double>( z );
}

inline cplx cplx::operator/( const double& r ) const {
    return std::complex<double>( *this ) / r;
}

inline cplx cplx::operator/( const int& i ) const {
    return std::complex<double>( *this ) / double( i );
}

inline cplx operator/( const double& r, const cplx& z ) {
    return r / std::complex<double>( z );
}

inline cplx operator/( const int& i, const cplx& z ) {
    return double( i ) / std::complex<double>( z );
}

inline cplx sin( const cplx& z ) {
    return sin( std::complex<double>( z ) );
}

inline cplx sinh( const cplx& z ) {
    return sinh( std::complex<double>( z ) );
}

inline cplx cos( const cplx& z ) {
    return cos( std::complex<double>( z ) );
}

inline cplx cosh( const cplx& z ) {
    return cosh( std::complex<double>( z ) );
}

inline cplx tan( const cplx& z ) {
    return tan( std::complex<double>( z ) );
}

inline cplx tanh( const cplx& z ) {
    return tanh( std::complex<double>( z ) );
}

inline cplx log10( const cplx& z ) {
    return log10( std::complex<double>( z ) );
}

inline cplx log( const cplx& z ) {
    return log( std::complex<double>( z ) );
}

inline cplx sqrt( const cplx& z ) {
    return sqrt( std::complex<double>( z ) );
}

inline cplx exp( const cplx& z ) {
    return exp( std::complex<double>( z ) );
}

inline cplx pow( const cplx& a, const cplx& b ) {
    return pow( std::complex<double>( a ), std::complex<double>( b ) );
}

inline cplx pow( const cplx& a, const double& b ) {
    return pow( std::complex<double>( a ), b );
}

inline cplx pow( const cplx& a, const int& b ) {
    return pow( std::complex<double>( a ), double( b ) );
}

inline cplx pow( const double& a, const cplx& b ) {
    return pow( a, std::complex<double>( b ) );
}

inline cplx pow( const int& a, const cplx& b ) {
    return pow( double( a ), std::complex<double>( b ) );
}
```

Additionally I do not see an assignment operator `operator=()` for your class `cplx`

And as a last note according to Eigen's site on `using custom scalar types` I do not see a specialization of `Eigen::NumTraits<T>` coming from their requirement of step 2:

> 2.add a specialization of struct Eigen::NumTraits (see NumTraits)

Comment: Hi Francis, 
Really appreciate your input.  I double checked cplx and the multiplication operator is defined for cplx*double and double*cplx to return a cplx.  Then the equals sign is cplx = cplx which is defined by inheriting form std::complex<double>.  I don't think this is the problem.  I've also tested that type of expression extensively outside of Eigen.  I'm not sure why Eigen isn't picking up the overloads correctly? or at least as intended by the cplx authors.

Comment: Yeah; I'm not sure either but the compiler is unable to resolve the ambiguity. I can check Eigen's site to see if they have a way to cast from one matrix type to another

Comment: @N.Burgess I made an edit after doing a couple more tests; check out my results; maybe this might help you to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: Francis, Thanks so much for all that work.  I got this cplx class from a friend at Umich.  I've used it for years without problems.  But you managed to uncover something very interesting that is likely messing with my NumTrait<cplx> definition.  I'll look into it over the weekend.  Again many thanks.

Comment: @N.Burgess Not a problem. The ironic part is I really don't know Eigen that well and I only learned about it a few months back when someone else was asking about it here on stack but it does seem like a nifty library to use. I am familiar with GLM though but the two libraries are quite different. I use GLM more often because of OpenGL & GLSL programming.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a similar issue, but using a class for dual numbers for the differentiation instead of complex (it's better- fewer operations, no epsilon sizing problems).

There are still some minor compiler issues, but anyway... in case these will help someone stumbling upon this question again in the future, here are the files to use the type with Eigen:

https://github.com/tesch1/CppNumericalSolvers/tree/templated/unsupported/Eigen/src/DualNum

Comment: Update: I packaged this work and wrote custom vectorization templates for x86_64+ to make it fast: https://gitlab.com/tesch1/cppduals - it also supports nesting of complex and dual for differentiating complex functions of the type discussed in the question.